# How do you repeat a javascript function a set number of times, at a set interval?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a player to get a prompt (I'm only in console), enter an answer, get feedback, wait a few seconds, have the same prompt come up again. This, for a set number of times.

I've tried using `setInterval` and `setTimeOut`, but to no avail, but maybe I'm just using them wrong?

In the code, the `scoredGame` function refers to the function I'm trying to run on repeat. If run by itself, it prompts the user for an input, gives a results, and stores it so that you can get an increasing "score" as the game goes on.

```
    let round = 0;

    function loopGame(){
        do {
            scoredGame();
            round++;
        }
        while (round < 5);
    }
```

It'd be super nice if anyone can tell me how to loop at set intervals (say every 5 or 10 seconds). Thanks!

**Edit:**

This is what the code that ended up working looks like.

```
    function looper(){
        if (round < 1){
            return console.log(
                "The game is over!" + whatScores()
            );
        } else {
            console.log(scoredGame());
            round--;
            setTimeout(() => console.log(looper()), 5000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you used with `setInterval` ?

Comment: it will be something like `var timer = setInterval(the function to call, the time in ms)`  and when you reach round 5, then `clearInterval(timer)`

Comment: show what you tried that did not work

Comment: how are you prompting the user? through `prompt`?

Comment: Unfortunately I deleted the setInterval function when it didn't work. I'm not familiar enough with Git to retrieve it... I'll see about putting it back together if the given answers don't work.

Comment: @zfrisch Yeah, I prompt them to enter rock, paper, scissors. I compare it to a random answer from the Math.random function and tell the person if they win or lose. It works up to the point where I'm trying to get the function to loop.

You can see more details here: https://github.com/Ahureau/rock-paper-scissors/blob/master/script.html

The part I'm not getting to work is marked YOU ARE HERE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did vote for [@JamesT’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57381754/117259), but here is another version that I made based on his great answer. There’s no mutation – it takes the number of repeats as a parameter.

```js
const yourFunction = () => console.log('hi')

function runner(repeats = 1) {
  if (repeats > 0) {
    yourFunction()
    setTimeout(() => runner(repeats - 1), 5000)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately I don't understand what the first line of code does. It's a function that returns "hi" in the console?

Comment: I tried it by using the following, but it essentially just prompts me 5 times with no sign of interaction with the rest of the code:

            function loop(repeats = 5){
                if (repeats > 0){
                    scoredGame();
                    setTimeout(() => loop(repeats - 1, 5000));
                }
            }

Edit: I'm terribly sorry about the formatting, I'm trying the different ways it showed me to have code in the message and none is working.

Comment: you need to call the function by running: `runner(5)`

Comment: and the first line is the function that you want to run. you can choose other function instead.

Comment: I was prompted twice and nothing was returned to the console. I replaced "yourFunction" by "scoredGame" (the name of the function I'm trying to call.

Comment: OK this is the closest I've been to getting it to work!

So TIL console.log is kind of like return but it doesn't stop the function?

I now have this as code:     function runner(repeats) {
        if (repeats > 0) {
            console.log(scoredGame());
            setTimeout(() => scoredGame(repeats - 1), 5000);
        }
    }

this gives me the result of the first prompt (though it still says undefined afterwards), but then it prompts me one more time with no results afterwards and no more prompts...

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can use setTimeout to rerun your loopGame function every 5 seconds after scoring is complete.

```
let round = 0;

function loopGame(){
    scoredGame();
    round++;
    if (round < 5) {
        setTimeout(loopGame, 5000)
    }
}
```

Comment: That actually looks a lot like one of the solutions I tried, but it just immediately asks for an input again. It tells me "undefined" as an output, and then after 5 seconds prompts me again. Also if I put nothing in the input it tells me that the value I inputted is "null" even though there's a different "path" for that type of answer.

Comment: Here's what the code it should refer to looks like:

```
    function scoredGame(){
        const winner = whoWins();    
        if (winner == WRONGCHOICE){
            return WRONGCHOICE;
        } else if (winner == LOSE){
            computerScore++;
            return LOSE + whatScores();
        } else if (whoWins == DRAW){
            return DRAW + whatScores();
        } else {
            playerScore++;
            return WIN + whatScores();
        }
    }

```

Comment: it sounds like you're getting the behavior you asked for: `then after 5 seconds prompts me again.` It sounds like you might be have some bugs in other parts of your code as well.

Comment: I've let the answer from @sascha run by itself and I don,t need to call the function for it to repeat 5 times. Unfortunately it also just keeps going. If you type slower it's still ready with the next prompt after 5 seconds.

The code itself is rather short, and I every individual part works without issues as far as I can tell: https://github.com/Ahureau/rock-paper-scissors/blob/master/script.html The part where I'm having issues has the YOU ARE HERE comment on it...

Comment: So I've looked over the code you linked to and if I paste in my solution where `YOU ARE HERE` comment is, and call `loopGame()` once, it prompts me, then after I hit ok, five seconds later I get another prompt. Also skipping input and just hitting ok seems to be handled fine as well. not sure how much help I can be without a specific problem or way to reproduce.

Comment: I thought since I was calling the scoredGame function it would, after each prompt, give me an output that is in line with that function (either win, lose, draw, or wrong choice if the input isn't rock, paper, or scissors).

I did the same thing calling whoWins in scoredGame and that worked, so I'm confused.

At the moment all I'm getting is a series of prompts that return nothing at any point. Or is that another piece of code I'm missing?

I appreciate you looking at it!

Comment: in `loopGame()` you need to console log the output from `scoredGame()` something like this: `console.log(scoredGame());` then you'll see your output in the console.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer:

You can create a Function that chains a timer a finite amount of times(`n`). To break the chain either of these needs to be true:

- the return value of the function ( `prompt` in this case )
- `n` is less than or equal to 0.

---

```
function promptFinite( msg, n, interval ) {
  let activeTimer = setTimeout( function timeFn() {
    let response = prompt( msg );
    if ( !response && --n > 0 ) {
      activeTimer = setTimeout( timeFn, interval );
    }
  }, interval );
}
```

---

### Example:

```js
function promptFinite( msg, n, interval ) {
  let activeTimer = setTimeout( function timeFn() {
    let response = prompt( msg );
    if ( !response && --n > 0 ) {
      activeTimer = setTimeout( timeFn, interval );
    }
  }, interval );
}



promptFinite( "name?", 3, 1000 );
```

---

### Adjusting for your code:

To use `promptFinite` in a way more resembling your code:

```
let round = 0;

function loopGame(){
    do {
        scoredGame();
        round++;
    }
    while (round < 5);
}
```

We can adjust the `prompt` to **require** an answer `n` amount of times. Though your code isn't very specific about what it's trying to accomplish, my understanding is that you require a score input `n` amount of times.

```
function promptScore( msg, n, interval ) {
  let activeTimer = setTimeout( function timeFn() {
    let response = prompt( msg );
    while(!response) {
      response = prompt( "required : " + msg);
    }
    if(--n > 0 ) {
      activeTimer = setTimeout( timeFn, interval );
    }
  }, interval );
}

promptScore( "score?", 3, 1000 );
```

---

### Example:

```js
function promptScore( msg, n, interval ) {
  let activeTimer = setTimeout( function timeFn() {
    let response = prompt( msg );
    while(!response) {
      response = prompt( "required : " + msg);
    }
    if(--n > 0 ) {
      activeTimer = setTimeout( timeFn, interval );
    }
  }, interval );
}



promptScore( "score?", 3, 1000 );
```

---

### Input Calculation: Getting the Total Score Example:

By altering the code just a bit more you can add up the `score`, and then call a function with the total value when the timers have finished. The below two calls show:

- the default: using `alert` to announce the score
- passing to `didIWin`: determining if I won( if `score > 100` )

---

```
function promptScore( msg, n, interval, fn = (msg) => alert("my score: " + msg) ) {
      let total = 0;

      let activeTimer = setTimeout( function timeFn() {
        let response = prompt( msg );
        while(!response || Number.isNaN(response)) {
          response = prompt( "required number : " + msg);
        }
        total += Number(response);

        if(--n > 0 ) {
          activeTimer = setTimeout( timeFn, interval );
        }
        else {
            fn(total);
        }
      }, interval );
    }


function didIWin(score) {
   alert("My Score: " + score + "\n" + (score > 100 ? "I won!" : "I lost!"));
}
    promptScore( "score?", 1, 1000); // default is to alert score

    promptScore( "score?", 3, 1000, didIWin); // pass score to outside function didIWin
```

---

### Example:

```js
function promptScore( msg, n, interval, fn = (msg) => alert("my score: " + msg) ) {
      let total = 0;
    
      let activeTimer = setTimeout( function timeFn() {
        let response = prompt( msg );
        while(!response || Number.isNaN(response)) {
          response = prompt( "required number : " + msg);
        }
        total += Number(response);
                  
        if(--n > 0 ) {
          activeTimer = setTimeout( timeFn, interval );
        }
        else {
            fn(total);
        }
      }, interval );
    }
    
    
function didIWin(score) {
   alert("My Score: " + score + "\n" + (score > 100 ? "I won!" : "I lost!"));
}
    promptScore( "simple alert: score?", 1, 1000); // default is to alert score
    
    promptScore( "did I win alert: score?", 3, 1000, didIWin); // pass score to outside function didIWin
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to call your function every 5 seconds for 5 times it's like this:

```js
function loopGame() {
 gameCount++;
 if (gameCount==5) clearInterval(timer);
        scoredGame();
};

var gameCount = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function(){loopGame()},5000);
```

I think it's better to use setInterval instead of setTimeout with doing it recursive.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm having the same issue I have with the other answers. The prompt returns immediately and no output is given. After the first 2 times it does take the timer into account though...